# passing argument to map, filter, sort function in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key

I am facing error while I am trying to pass Value(**sortBy** ) inside the sort(callback) function.

```js
 let sortBy = 'birth'
     let usersJSON = [
     {
      name: "Sania Mirza",
      birth: "11/30/2011"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/1999"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/2020 "
     }
]

   
    usersJSON.sort(function (a, b) {
     //var dateA = new Date(a.birth), dateB = new Date(b.birth); // this is working fine 
     var dateA = new Date(a.sortBy), dateB = new Date(b.sortBy); // I want sorting based on "sortBy"  
     return dateA - dateB;
    });
    console.log("componentDidMount :", JSON.stringify(usersJSON, null, ' '))
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `a[sortBy]` . This is same as dot notation except the fact that `sortBy` may come from a variable whereas when you do `a.sortyBy`, it looks up for a key `sortyBy` (string), not a dynamic variable and hence you get the error.

```js
let sortBy = 'birth'
     let usersJSON = [
     {
      name: "Sania Mirza",
      birth: "11/30/2011"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/1999"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/2020 "
     }
]

   
    usersJSON.sort(function (a, b) {
     //var dateA = new Date(a.birth), dateB = new Date(b.birth); // this is working file 
     var dateA = new Date(a[sortBy]), dateB = new Date(b[sortBy]); // I want sorting based on "sortBy"  
     return dateA - dateB;
    });
    console.log(usersJSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let sortBy = 'birth'
     let usersJSON = [
     {
      name: "Sania Mirza",
      birth: "11/30/2011"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/1999"
     }, {
      name: "Lata Pathak",
      birth: "10/31/2020 "
     }
]

   
    usersJSON.sort(function (a, b) {
     //var dateA = new Date(a.birth), dateB = new Date(b.birth); // this is working file 
     var dateA = new Date(a[sortBy]), dateB = new Date(b[sortBy]); // I want sorting based on "sortBy"  
     return dateA - dateB;
    });
    console.log("componentDidMount :", JSON.stringify(usersJSON, null, ' '))
```